# Comparing the location of values in different tables

Tags: subquery

New to SQL. Hope to find distinct pizza sold by restaurants that are located in the same area as bob (customer).

Database schema:

Customers(cname, area)

Restaurants(rname, area)

Pizzas(pizza)

Sells(rname,pizza,price)

Likes(cname, pizza)

```
   SELECT distnct pizza
   FROM Sells
   WHERE rname in (
      SELECT rname
      FROM Restaurants
      WHERE area..... 
   -- This is the part where i don't know how to continue. 
   -- How do i write it so that i compare the location of the restaurant with bob's location? 
   );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that a combination of an `INNER JOIN` and `EXISTS` should do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(s.pizza)
FROM dbo.Sells s
INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants r
    ON s.rname = r.rname
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Customers
             WHERE cname = 'bob'
             AND area = r.area) 
;
```